# Disjoint global elements

Tags: category-theory

In the paper *Axiomatizing a Category of Categories* by Colin McLarty, the axiom PCC1 is stated as follows:

> The global elements 0 and 1 of $\mathbf{2}$ are disjoint. Their pullback is $\emptyset$.

Here is some context: 0 and 1 are functors $\mathbf{1} \to \mathbf{2}$, $\mathbf{1}$ is terminal in "the category of categories" (which is axiomatized) and $\emptyset$ is an initial object in that category.

It is the first occurrence of the word "disjoint" in that paper. What is its definition? (I could only find the definition of "disjoint coproduct").

Comment: I won't make this an answer right now since I am not absolutely sure what McLarty means here, but to me ''disjoint'' just means that the pullback is empty (or rather, the initial object in whatever category you are talking about), because for things like sets and spaces, you capture the correct visual intuition with this. So could it be the sentence ''Their pullback is $\varnothing$.'' is just McLarty explaining what ''disjoint'' means to him?

Comment: I would agree with Daniel but to consider a pullback you need to provide some arrows... so what, the pullback of $0\rightarrow ??\leftarrow 1$ where $??$ is... what, exactly? This seems a bit unclear

Comment: @FShrike : 0 and 1 are arrows from $\mathbf{1}$ to $\mathbf{2}$.

Comment: @DaniëlApol it's a complete answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since people in the comments agreed, we can put my comment into an answer: given a category $\mathscr{C}$ with pullbacks, an initial object, and a terminal object, we say two global elements of the same object (or even two general maps with the same target) in $\mathscr{C}$ are *disjoint* by definition when their pullback in $\mathscr{C}$ is the initial object. So the sentence ''Their pullback is $\varnothing$'' is McLarty explaining what ''disjoint'' means in this context.

Comment: I am now convinced that indeed two global elements of the same object are disjoint by definition when their pullback is the initial object. Also, I am convinced that it makes sense to generalize this definition with two monomorphisms with the same target. I am a bit circumspect if it makes sense to generalize it with two any morphisms with the same target.

Comment: @Bruno The definition is indeed standard for any cospan of morphisms.

Comment: @Bruno, for general morphisms with the same target, you can think about them being disjoint as sort of saying their images are disjoint subobjects of the target. (But in a general category, the lack of images of morphisms makes that you can't make this precise.)